# Java how to specify a method that takes a subclass of a superclass

Tags: java, inheritance, wildcard

Here is what I want to do:

```
public MyClass extends MySuperClass{

}


public class MySuperClass {

public static void main( String[] args ) { 
MyClass mc = setProperties( new Myclass() );
}

public static Class<? extends MySuperClass> setProperties(Class<? extends MySuperClass> myClass){
// set some static properties
return myClass;
}

}
```

I want to be able to pass any subclass of MySuperClass to setPropterties and return it after setting some properties in the superclass. Returning it is just for convinence. Am I just missing some syntax ? or is my understanding of Class and wildcards incorrect?

Right now I get: The method setProperties(Class) in the type MySuperClass is not applicable for the arguments (MyClass)

Comment: You are requiring the `Class` object be passed instead of an instance of it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to be able to pass any subclass of MySuperClass to setPropterties and return it after setting some properties in the superclass. Returning it is just for convinence. Am I just missing some syntax ? or is my understanding of Class

```
public static MySuperClass setProperties(MySuperClass superClass)
{
      // Accept any instance or subclass of MySuperClass
      return superClass;
}
```

**The use of `Class<?>`**

This represents the *unknown* type. (Spooky). It basically means you don't know what class type this method is going to return.

*Useful Link* : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html

Comment: Given OP's description, this solution fits it well. Although I must admit, I'm more proving a point.

Comment: Oh that was simple, thanks Chris, I was making things complicated :)

Comment: Ha, wow. I was partly being sarcastic. Don't let anyone tell you sarcasm doesn't have it's uses!

Comment: I can't accept your answer for some time, but what is the use of Class<?> then?

Comment: Best example I can think of for Class<?> is something like a json/xml parser.  It takes the string to be parsed, and a Class that tells it what it's supposed to be turned into/return.  public static <X> X jsonConversion(String json, Class<X> clazz)